# Vertical menu appears horitontal in Opera

Tags: html, css, opera

So I have a vertical menu that appears properly in firefox and chrome. However, it appears horizontal in Opera. I really think it's just a simple adjustment in the code, but I can't seem to narrow it in!

```
#liststyle2 {
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    background-color: #ececec;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style: none;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
}

#liststyle2 li {
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
}

#liststyle2 li a {
    padding: 17px 25px 15px 25px;
    font-size: 15px;
    float: left;
    min-width: 77px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #a3a3a3;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#liststyle2 li a:hover{
    background-color: #e2e1e1;
}

#liststyle2 li:last-child a{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better if I have html code .

I think that you should remove this option :

```
#liststyle2 li a {
    float: left;
}
```

If you have to float these `li a` to left. You have to set `#liststyle2 li a` width equal to the width of `#liststyle2`.

Answer (score 0):

For each browser's engine, different transition prefixes are required. Add following too:

```
-o-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-o-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-o-border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
-o-border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
```

in your `#liststyle2`.

Read more on [Opera](http://www.opera.com/docs/specs/presto2.12/)'s docs.